# Can't find stderr print in python smtpd

Tags: python, smtpd

I am using smtpd and its catching ValueError exceptions I raise in process_message and printing a description to stderr instead of raising the error. 
What it prints out is the string I construct the ValueError with.

So if I do this in process_message:

```
raise ValueError("550, This is the error")
```

I see

```
550, This is the error
```

on the console.
I cannot for the life of me find what code is causing the print. Is there  anyway to override stderr to show a stacktrace each time something is printed or otherwise locate what lines of code are printing out these lines?

Comment: You didn't even say *WHAT* it prints out. So I don't any luck at looking for that error message in my `/usr/lib/python2.7/smtpd.py` file ...   however, if I search for ValueError in that file, it looks like you provided the local and remote port in a way that int() cannot work with it. Use a number, not the service name.

Comment: Sorry, What it prints out is the string I construct the ValueError with
So if I do 
ValueError("550, This is the error")
I see
550, This is the error
on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace one the standard output streams with something that traces invocations of `write()`:

```
import sys
import traceback

class FileTracer(object):
    def __init__(self, out):
        self.out = out

    def write(self, data):
        traceback.print_stack(None, None, sys.__stderr__)
        self.out.write(data)

    def flush(self):
        self.out.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.out.close()

sys.stderr = FileTracer(sys.stderr)

sys.stderr.write("trigger\n")
sys.stderr.flush()
```

Note that I'm using `__stderr__` to avoid loops.